# git takes huge time to build when I change my branch

Tags: eclipse, git

My eclipse if loaded with lot of code (12-15 projects). Now when I switch from one git branch to another, eclipse starts rebuilding entire work-space consuming roughly 40 mins :( Is there any way I can dictate git to build only classes where it find changes.

Comment: The problem is that probably the modification date of the files is changed, and thus `make` things it should rebuild everything.

Comment: Turn off auto-rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very simple problem. In Eclipse you have normally all projects open at the same time. That need a lot of Resources because when you make changes Eclipse goes over the complete tree and check if there are changes or not.

First solution is to close all other projects and open only that project you're working in.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_close_project.htm

Our the second one is to use another IDE with less overhead and a better performance. I don't write here some good IDEs otherwise we have here a Shitstorm because everybody mean that his IDE is better :D and it depends on your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Git FAQ on [Why isn't Git preserving modification time on files?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F) here (please make sure to also read the non-quoted part of the FAQ):

> Git sets the current time as the timestamp on every file it modifies, but only those. The other files are left untouched, which means build tools will be able to depend on modification time and rebuild properly.

So while Git does not maintain the modified time for files that change between branches, it does maintain the modified time for files that do not change. That said, you probably simply have a lot of changed files between your branches.